# AngularJS 1.2 Animation fallback when no-cssanimations supported

Tags: angularjs

I'm using the new AngularJS 1.2 approach ([year of moo article](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html)) for animations using CSS3 transitions. I'd like to conditionally apply a fallback jQuery animation if the browser doesn't support CSS animations.

- My CSS animations are working fine when only using CSS ng-enter, ng-enter-active, etc.
- My jQuery animations are working fine when using app.animations("...") as shown below
- I'm using Modernizr so the .no-cssanimations class is already applied to my html document.
- I'd like to conditionally apply the jQuery animation when CSS animations aren't supported for browsers such as IE9.

Right now, I'm trying to do it through the class selector **".no-cssanimations .slideup-form"** like this...

```
//Simplified angular animation example
app.animation("**.no-cssanimations .slideup-form**", function () {
     return {
          enter: function (element, done) { ... },
          leave: function (element, done) { ... }
          }
});
```

That's not working. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Thanks...

**UPDATE**:

I wasn't able to figure out the selector approach above - but I have it working by conditionally calling app.animation() by testing the Modernizr object in javascript. I didn't realize you could test like this.

```
if (Modernizr.canvas) { ... }
```

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I think app.animation is the way to go if you want to do JavaScript animations. Is your selector `**.no-cssanimations .slideup-form**` hitting anything?

Comment: I've verified the selector is valid using a simple CSS test -- but app.animation() doesn't seem to find it. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use a complex selector like that in your animation() factory method. You can only use a single CSS class name for one level. Instead make your animation factory method conditional based on the browser's capabilities by using $sniffer to detect if you have the transitions there or not.

```
//you can make this an EMPTY string if you want this animation to apply to ALL
//possible elements...
app.animation('.slideup-form', function($sniffer) {
  if(!$sniffer.transitions) {
    //this object will conditionally be added if the browser doesn't support
    //native CSS3 animations
    return {
      enter             : function(element, done) {},
      leave             : function(element, done) {},
      move              : function(element, done) {},
      beforeAddClass    : function(element, className, done) {},
      addClass          : function(element, className, done) {},
      beforeRemoveClass : function(element, className, done) {},
      removeClass       : function(element, className, done) {}
    }
  }
});
```

Just remember to call done() in your JS animation code. Also upgrade to 1.2.5.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer - I didn't know about $sniffer - good stuff!